# Firebase cannot find 'module <Firebase>'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to reference my Firebase class but it's saying I can't find the module...This is strange because everything else in my Firebase is working like:
    `FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail`
is working no problem and signing in works too
but when I'm trying to do
    `let firebase = Firebase(url: "url.com")`
I get my module not found problem...
[image: error]

I'm fairly certain I installed it correctly and I tried to follow the advice that people have posted on here already but I'm either doing it wrong or can't figure it out. This is what my build phases looks like. [image: build phase]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use old firebase, use Firebase sdk 2.5.0.

If you are using cocoapods:

```
pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.0'
```

This will fix your problem and you wont need google service plist

This is just if you want to use the old one. Using new sdk will solve your problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has been updated to firebase 3 recently. In firebase 3, the information to your firebase url is provided in `GoogleService-Info.plist`. you just have to download it from your firebase console and put in your folders

more information can be found here https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

Comment: what i meant is that you do not need to put `let firebase = Firebase(url: "url.com")`. googleservice-info.plist settles that for you

Comment: ohhh thank you! That  would explain why everything else works

Comment: just wondering, since i don't need to do let firebase = Firebase(url: "url.com"), how would i want to reference that variable later? I'm trying to do:
ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            println(snapshot.value)
            }, withCancelBlock: { error in
                println(error.description)
        })
    }
but I don't have the variable ref since i never did let var = Firebase(url:"")

Comment: `ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()` and you can start doing things like `filesRef = ref.child("files")`

Answer (score 1):

FireBase(url:) is depreciated.replace with the below code for swift 3

let dataBaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("child name").child(subchildname)